# Paste Script: Warning: could not load entry point app (ImportError: No module named app)

Tags: python, paste, paster

I'm developing small project with ability scaffold (copy project files as an template).
Truing to build my project by following [this tutorial](http://lucasmanual.com/mywiki/PythonPaste)
This is what official documentation suggests.

> mkvirtuallenv app

than

> paster create app

than added in my `setup.py`

> entry_points="""
>
> ```
>   [paste.paster_create_template]
>   app = app.app:FrameworkTemplate
>
>   """,
> ```

than

from paste.script import templates

> class FrameworkTemplate(templates.Template):
>
> ```
>     egg_plugins = ['app']
>     summary = 'Template for creating a basic Framework package'
>     required_templates = ['basic_package']
>     _template_dir = 'templates'
>     use_cheetah = True
> ```

crated my templates folder and package folder in `app/templates/+package+/`

than

> python setup.py develop

And here is my finish:
When I do

> paster create --list-templates

It says me that:

> Warning: could not load entry point app (ImportError: No module named
>   app)

I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong? And hot to make it work

When I run `python` console and import app it is importing with no problems.

Dublicated this question in official [issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ianb/pastescript/issue/15/warning-could-not-load-entry-point-app) of pasterScript:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app is not installed as app.app, instead of app.
Try edit setup.py endpoint:

```
entry_points="""

  [paste.paster_create_template]
  app = app:FrameworkTemplate

  """,
```